# Flutter: local notification plugin, navigate to specific screen when the user tap the notification

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I`m using local notification plugin and everything works fine except that when i tap on the notification.i want to navigate to specific screen when the user tap the notification

```
Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    //convert payload json to notification model object
    try{
    Map notificationModelMap = jsonDecode(payload);
    NotificationModel model = NotificationModel.fromJson(notificationModelMap);

    await Navigator.push(
        context,// it`s null!
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CommitmentPage(model)));}
            catch(e){print(e.toString());}
  }
```

but the context always null and gives me an exception
`NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null`.

**Edit**

i tried to use navigatorKey and pass it to material app as suggested by @Günter Zöchbauer but it gives me another exception

```
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

static final navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey:navigatorKey ,
      title: 'notification',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: new RootPage(auth: new Auth(),),
    );
  }

}
```

**ReminderPage**

```
   class ReminderPage extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
      _ReminderPageState createState() => _ReminderPageState();

    }

class _ReminderPageState extends State<ReminderPage> {
  final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
....

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initLocalNotification();
....

  }


// this method is called when u tap on the notification
 Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {

    //convert payload json to notification model object
    Map notificationModelMap = jsonDecode(payload);
    NotificationModel model = NotificationModel.fromJson(notificationModelMap);

    try{
   await Navigator.push(
        MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState.context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CommitmentPage(model)));}
            catch(e){print(e.toString());}


  }

}
```

**Edit 2**
instead of using

```
 await Navigator.push(
            MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState.context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => CommitmentPage(model)));}
                catch(e){print(e.toString());}
```

i used

```
await  MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CommitmentPage(model)));
```

and it worked fine, but when i tap on the notification after killing the app, it takes me to the home page not to the desired one! 
i think navigatorKey has not been initialized yet!

Comment: Can you share some more code? How to you call your notification ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest change you've done, you being taken to the home page, is more to do with the fact that you instantiate and initialise the plugin a couple of pages further in your app. considering the app got killed, the plugin would've been killed too. you should look into initialising the plugin closer to when your app starts e.g. around when the app is created or when the first page is created, depending on the behaviour you want. In this issue https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/99, another dev has been able to change the first page shown if the app is killed but that may different to what you want to happen.

Answer (score 16):

**1. FMC payload**

```
{
  "notification": {
    "body": "Hey, someone book your product", 
    "title": "production booking"
  }, 
  "priority" : "high",
  "data": {
    "action" : "BOOKING" //to identify the action
  },
  "to": "deviceFCMId"
}
```

**2. Set the payload data in localnotification.show method**

```
showNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
  String action = message.data['action']; // get the value set in action key from FCM Json in Step1
  // local notification to show to users using the created channel.
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
            android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: iOSNotificationDetails),
        payload: action // set the value of payload
    );
  }
}
```

**3. Create a navigatorKey in MyApp class**

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
      GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator"); //
}
```

**4. Set navigatorkey on your MaterialApp**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //this change the status bar color to white
    return MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    ....
```

**5. on initState, init localnotificationPlugin and declare the onSelectNotification method**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }

  Future<dynamic> onSelectNotification(payload) async {
  // implement the navigation logic
  }
```

**6. Navigation logic example**

```
Future<dynamic> onSelectNotification(payload) async {
// navigate to booking screen if the payload equal BOOKING
if(payload == "BOOKING"){
 this.navigatorKey.currentState.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BookingScreen()),
   (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: In 5), how do you plan to use the context without it? in initState() there is no context available for onSelectNotification() to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Pass a `navigatorKey` to `MaterialApp` and use this key to get the context. This context contains a `Navigator` and you can use it to switch to whatever page you want.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html

Comment: i created final navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); and passed it to material app, but when i access it from another staefull widget it always null. is this the proper way to access it   GlobalKey().currentState.context;

Comment: You need to store a reference to the key in a "global" or static variable to ensure you access the same instance everywhere. If it doesn't work please add the updated code to your question so it can be investigated.

Comment: Try `await  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () => MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CommitmentPage(model))));` to give the app some time to initialize. You can try reduce the delay, it might even work with `Duration.zero` instead of `const Duration(milliseconds: 200)`.

Comment: U saved me after 5 hours :)